# Unable to create a non reactive RenderPlot object with dynamic names in R

Tags: r, plot, dynamic, shiny, render

I want to create a `plotOutput object`, which is dynamically created.

I've created dynamic objects to render different plots, they have different "Data" passed so the plot will vary.

The `renderPlot` function is then saved in Graph1, Graph2, Graph3 and so on how many ever times i is created. Then the UI element "w" has the plotOutput of Graph1, Graph2 and so on.

But when I call "w" The latest Graph is rendered and overwritten in all the objects of w.

**Is there any other way to do it?**

```
output[[paste0("Graph",i)]]<-{ renderPlot({ggplot2(Data,aes(x=xxval,y=yval)+geom_point() } 
w<-plotOutput(paste0("Graph",i),height=200,width=300)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to use the function `insertUI` for this. And I thank you - I have finally found a use-case where you have to put the output within an observer. Here is a working example

```
library(ggplot2)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    column(
      width = 3,
      actionButton(
        inputId = "newGraph",
        label = "add Graph"
      ),
      selectInput(
        inputId = "xAxis",
        label = "x-axis",
        choices = colnames(mtcars)
      ),
      selectInput(
        inputId = "yAxis",
        label = "y-axis",
        choices = colnames(mtcars)
      )
    ),
    column(
      width = 9,
      id = "graph_wrapper"
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output,session) {
  observeEvent(input$newGraph,{
    insertUI(
      selector = '#graph_wrapper',
      where = "beforeEnd",
      ui = plotOutput(
        outputId = paste0("plot",input$newGraph)
      ))
    xxval = input$xAxis
    yval = input$yAxis
    output[[paste0("plot",input$newGraph)]] = renderPlot({
      ggplot(mtcars,aes_string(x=xxval,y=yval))+geom_point() 
    })
  })  
  })
)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: OMG this is amazing!!!!
Thanks for the quick response and working example.  It means a lot

Comment: @VedhaViyash Hi Vedya, please consider [accepting this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it has solved your issue.